# Mobile page disabled when sidebar off in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, mobile, sidebar, core-ui

I'm using coreui in vuejs and in mobile browser(android,chrome) when sidebar off , page stay disabled and i have to refresh to keep working
can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why that happens is because the event's not firing when you tap/click out of the menu. It's because the package is buggy, so there's no way you can fix it without the package getting the bugfix.

https://github.com/coreui/coreui-vue/issues/229

As a temporary workaround, you can use css to completely disable the backdrop so it doesn't come in the way as such:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .sidebar-backdrop {
        visibility: hidden !important;
    }
}
```